# worker_concurrency configuration not valid for celery

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

environment: Django3.1, celery5.2
Django setting.py

```py
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1/0'
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 2  # 并发worker数
# CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=1
CELERYD_FORCE_EXECV = True 
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 50
```

celery.py

```py
import os

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'san.settings')

app = Celery('san')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

启动命令:`celery -A san worker -l INFO  -P gevent`

-------------- celery@dev.10.1.1.209 v5.2.3 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.17 2022-02-18 14:31:44

- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         san:0x7f7d31a811c0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (gevent)
  -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
  --- ***** -----
  -------------- [queues]
  .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery

concurrency: 4,why does my configuration not take effect?
Specifying the '-c' parameter in the startup command is valid.

- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (gevent)

What can I do to make my configuration work?

The rest of my configuration works,such as `CELERY_BROKER_URL`,`CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`

Comment: not clear on what help you are looking for? are you saying the -c option is not working for you while starting the worker process?

Comment: The CELERYD_CONCURRENCY configuration does not work in a Django configuration. What should I do to make setting.py's CELERYD_CONCURRENCY configuration work

Comment: CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND,CELERY_BROKER_URL are in effect in the configuration, but CELERYD_CONCURRENCY is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
```

Change `CELERYD CONCURRENCY` to `CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY`